# INFO [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-apr-8080-exec-13] Error status 408 Read timed out

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I am getting below error multiple times while deleting some contents from alfresco repository.

```
 2017-02-08 11:46:41,451  INFO  [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-apr-8080-exec-3] Error status 408 Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
   at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor578.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy313.receiveResponseHeader(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
   at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.service(RemoteClient.java:1095)
   at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.RemoteClient.call(RemoteClient.java:745)
   at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:143)
   at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.AuthenticatingConnector.call(AuthenticatingConnector.java:293)
   at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.EndPointProxyController.handleRequestInternal(EndPointProxyController.java:326)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
```

And i am not able to delete content.

Can any one have faced same issue?

Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can anyone please help me with above issue?

Comment: How many files are you trying to delete? The timeout suggests the client has timed out, but the delete could still be running. If you're deleting a folder it may help to delete files in smaller batches (ie 1 sub folder at a time). Any other errors in the log?

Comment: @ConsultStan There is no any other Error.  Can I increase that time-out period by doing any change in configuration.